# Get centroids from datapoints in pandas DF for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe

```
id    code    lat    long
1      100    22.6    42.3
1      200    23.6    45.3
1      400    21.6    46.3
2      300    22.6    42.3
2      500    22.6    42.3
2      800    22.6    42.3
3      100    22.6    42.3
```

i want to find the centre points grouping on id column,
and return a dataframe :

```
id    centre_lat   centre_long
1      xx.xx        yy.yy
2      xx.xx        yy.yy
3      xx.xx        yy.yy
```

Since id 3 has only 1 code, therefore the same lat long is the centroid for that id.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [136]: df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['lat','long'].mean()
Out[136]:
   id   lat       long
0   1  22.6  44.633333
1   2  22.6  42.300000
2   3  22.6  42.300000
```

Comment: a small doubt wouldn't the point between the smallest and largest lat and long is also a center ? Better to ask Op for expected output. There might be a need for `isclose()`

Comment: @Dark, due to [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) - it's a simple `mean` value for each dimension

Comment: Thank you for that I never thought of the three points to from a triangle. Anyway I have voted :)

Comment: @Dark, i didn't even doubt :-)